# PHP time() method not giving timestamp of my timezone

Tags: php, android

I have a php code which inserts the timestamp in the database for every insert.

I use: `time()` method to get the time Stamp. but when I send this time Stamp to the mobile client it shows some other time.

How do I get the timestamp for my current time zone, `Asia/Calcutta`.

Here is my PHP code:

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
 $timeStamp = time();
 //insert into notification table
 $sql = "insert into notifications (senderUsername,notificationText,timeStamp) values ('$senderUsername','$resultTextValue','$timeStamp')";
```

This store the value in the DB as `1420829504`

This when parsed on my Android client it shows as `January 9th 2015, 18:51:44` but I except it as  `January 10th 2015, 00:21:44`

I have already deployed my application on the Play Store, so the only thing I can play with is my server side code.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? What code have you tried so far? We are not here to write your project for you.

Comment: It shows the timestamp of your php ini setting. Set the value in your php ini to `date.timezone = Asia/Calcutta`

Comment: @Zerp helping me in getting a timeStamp correctly doesnt means you are writing a project for me.

Comment: See [user contributed note #73](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#100220) in the PHP docs

Comment: @username_AB "The documentation should have this info. The function time() returns always timestamp that is timezone independent (=UTC)." on http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#100220. You should convert it back to the proper time zone in the client (your app). Or to fix it as a workaround add `19200` to the timestamp. That adds 5.5 hours to the timestamp generated as UTC.

Comment: @Mouser Will try the workaround

Comment: @Mouser Thanks man! Your answer made it. Thanks alot. By the way i had to add `19800` to add 5.5 hours.

Comment: @username_AB Glad to be of service. Made a slight calculation error. Brains are already in weekend mode. I you get the chance update your app with proper coding returning the localized time value calculated from a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your time zone on a per project basis for php like so.

`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');`

Comment: I tried this but it is still giving 1420828525 for 12:05

Comment: @username_AB you need to provide us with more of your code

Answer (score 0):

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $time = time();
    $actual_time = date('M d Y, 00:H:i',$time);
```

use $actual_time in you sql database